# FirstOrDefaultAsync causes NullReferenceException in NgsqlConnection using .NET on Azure

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, dependency-injection

I am working on a small project that will basically pull info from a REST Api, store it in Azure Postgres db and then feed info to a Power BI dashboarding using the db. Right now I am stuck on a POC because I cannot seem to get FirstOrDefaultAsync working. I can switch to using the non async version, but that's not what I want. Here's what I have so far:

```
internal class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            // setup IoC
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IClusterRepository, ClusterRepository>();
            
            // set up db connection
            var postgreServer = KeyVault.Instance.GetSecret("PostgreServer");
            var postgreDbName = "postgres";//KeyVault.Instance.GetSecret("PostgreDbName");
            var postgrePort = KeyVault.Instance.GetSecret("PostgrePort");
            var postgreAdminUser = KeyVault.Instance.GetSecret("PostgreAdminUser");
            var postgreAdminPassword = KeyVault.Instance.GetSecret("PostgreAdminPassword");

            var connectionString =
                $"Host={postgreServer}.postgres.database.azure.com;" +
                $"Database={postgreDbName};" +
                $"Port={postgrePort};" +
                $"User Id={postgreAdminUser};" +
                $"Password={postgreAdminPassword};" +
                "Ssl Mode=Require;";

            builder.Services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
                            .AddDbContext<ClusterHealthDashboardDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));
        }
    }
```

And then in my dbContext I have:

```
public class ClusterHealthDashboardDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ClusterHealthDashboardDbContext()
        {
        }

        public ClusterHealthDashboardDbContext(DbContextOptions<ClusterHealthDashboardDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<ClusterDto> Clusters { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ClusterDto>().ToTable("clusters", "cluster_health_dashboard");
        }

        public async Task<ClusterDto> GetAsync(Int64 id)
        {
            return await this.Clusters.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        }
}
```

I can share my proj file if that helps.. i dunno what's up, but the closest i've come is finding out that this line causes null reference:

StackTrace  "   at Npgsql.TypeHandlers.TextHandler..ctor(PostgresType postgresType, NpgsqlConnection connection)\r\n
at Npgsql.TypeHandlers.UnknownTypeHandler..ctor(NpgsqlConnection connection)\r\n
at Npgsql.TypeMapping.ConnectorTypeMapper..ctor(NpgsqlConnector connector)\r\n
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.d__149.MoveNext()\r\n
at ...
C:\...\ClusterHealthDashboardDbContext.cs:line 169"   string

a coworker looked on git and found that in the TextHandler constructor the NpgsqlConnection connection is  likely null.. but how could  that be? Am I missed a using statement? Is the connection being disposed of?  Am I doing Dependency Injection wrong?

Comment: How are you calling `GetAsync`

Comment: You are getting only the FIRST and not all the data.  Try GetAsync.

Comment: @MichaelRandall from within another async/await method

Comment: @jdweng yes that is the intention, to the the first element that matches the Id column. It's weird how the methods work in synchronous calls but NOT async

Comment: With HTTP can be received in chunks and you need the entire message to be able to parse the results.  HTTP has open/closed tags and the parser needs both.  Your code is only getting the first chunk which doesn't have the closing tag so you get an exception.

Comment: @jdweng and how do i ensure entity framework requests the entire chunk with closing tags?

Comment: Do not use a FIRST method!!! Or loop until you get all the chunks.

Comment: @jdweng um.. there is only 1 row in my table, it's a really small proof of concept.. FirstOrDefaultAsync is expected to return 1 object. Did you understand the part about the connection being null? I think it has something to do with the way Entity Framework disposes of objects

Comment: I just do not think you got the entire message and that is why you have a null;

Comment: And is there some way in C# or .NET or EntityFramework to tell it to get the whole message?

Comment: @MichaelRandall I should have answered your question first as I figured out the problem.. i was calling it from a higher level service that was basically doing:

```public async void GetHealhResponse() 

I thought the void async would be fine, but apparently it broke the chain of async/awaits and caused the Connection to get disposed.

Comment: @StephenLee bazinga!